# How to handle a request by POST on a Next.js 13 page

Tags: typescript, redirect, post, next.js, next.js13

I have an e-commerce site built with Next.js 13 with Typescript.

In the checkout the user complete their information and send it to the backend to create an order in my backend. Then, is redirected to external page for payment (service called Fiserv or Firstdata) with credit and debit card. When the transaction is done, the user is redirected again to the thank you page inside /page folder on Next.js structure, but this redirect is by post of a form, and the thank you page returns a status 405.

How can I handle this? Is it possible to force the method from POST to GET? Can I receive the POST data and use it on the page?

Thanks

I tried to use GET() and POST() functions in /app/my-path/route.ts to redirect to user, but on the POST() method crash.